# C file size discrepency

Tags: c, filesize, file-pointer

I am trying to learn C, and am currently working on a toy script.
Right now, it simply opens a text file, reads it char by char, and 
spits it out onto the command line.

I looked up how to see the size of a file (using fseek() and then ftell()),
but the result it returns doesn't match up with the number I get from counting the characters in a while loop as I iterate through the file.

I'm wondering if the discrepency is due to windows using \r\n and not just \n, since the discrepency seems to be #newlines+1.

Below is the script I am working on:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
        FILE * fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");

        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
        char * stringOfFile = malloc(ftell(fp));
        printf("allocated %d characters for file\n", ftell(fp));
        fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);//reset pointer

        char tmp = getc(fp); //current letter in file
        int i=0;
        while (tmp != EOF) //End-Of-File (defined in stdio.h)
        {
                *(stringOfFile+i) = tmp;
                tmp = getc(fp);
                i++;
        }
        fclose(fp);
        printf("Turns out we had %d characters to store.\nThe file was as follows:\n", i);
        printf("%s", stringOfFile);
}
```

And the output I get (with a simple test file you can see from the output) is:

```
allocated 67 characters for file
Turns out we had 60 characters to store.
The file was as follows:
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
(last)line6

lmnopqrstuvw▬$YL Æ
```

where the tail bits of the printing seem to be garbage from allocating too much memory to the string.

Thanks in advance for any help/answer you can provide!

Comment: I think it would be more easier your for to read the file line by line with `fgets`. Also don't forget, that when you are `malloc`ing for a string, do not forget about the terminating `'\0'`.

Comment: Note that file sizes can exceed, INT_MAX,  the maximum returned from `ftell()` and even `SIZE_MAX`.

Comment: Note that `fgetc()` returns an `int`, not a `char`; it can return every value that can be represented by a `char` and also one extra value, EOF.  You cannot identify EOF reliably if you store the result of `fgetc()` directly into a `char`, but the different forms of 'unreliable identification' depend on whether `char` is signed or unsigned, and to some extend on the code set you work with.

Comment: You haven't specified your OS, but `fseek()`/`ftell()` to get the size of a file isn't strictly conforming C.  `fseek()` to the end of a file opened in binary mode [is explicitly undefined behavior per footnote 268 of the C standard.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note268), and `ftell()` on a file opened in text mode doesn't return a value useful for anything other than returning to that position - it's [not an indicator of the number of bytes](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.4p2)

Answer (score 3):

If you're running windows:

```
FILE * fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
```

opens the file in *text* mode which implies `\r\n` conversion to `\n`

So if your file has 7 lines, the conversion removes 7 chars (that is, if the file was using Windows-style line termination)

The fix is to open it in binary mode

```
FILE * fp = fopen("test.txt", "rb");
```

so `ftell` and reading chars one by one should match.

Of course, that's wasting space & not very convenient to have `\r` chars in your text, so you could allocate like you're doing, and in the end perform a `realloc` to shrink down the allocated memory with the actual number of chars (since it's smaller, it's ok)

```
stringOfFile = realloc(stringOfFile,i+1);
```

Note that since I've taken the need to add the nul-terminator into account, I've added 1 to the number of chars, so if there aren't any `\r` chars in the file, the `realloc` could increase the size of the block by 1.

So, as I was hinting at, don't forget to nul-terminate your string or `printf` doesn't stop properly:

```
stringOfFile[i] = '\0';
```

(unless you don't care about creating a C-string, since storing the string size + display char-by-char is also correct)

We've see that the `ftell` method is tricky, and in some cases, when the stream is for instance the output of a command (`popen` returns a `FILE *` but you cannot `fseek` it) or a socket, whatever, this principle cannot be applied since we don't know the size of the data in advance.

In the general case, it would be better to:

- allocate a small buffer
- read char by char and store
- if buffer is full, call `realloc` to increase the size by some step (not at every char, performance would be bad)
- in the end, call `realloc` again to adjust the size more precisely

(that solves the binary/text issue transparently as well)

Note that if you're working with large files (>4GB) you have to use 64-bit unsigned integers for positions and `fopen64` flavours of I/O functions (and all offset variables like `i` should be unsigned / conform to return type of `ftell` or you'll start having problems at 2GB). Well, I suppose it doesn't matter much when processing moderately small text files.

Also, check David answer. With text files, putting the result of `getc` in a `char` should work, but not in the general case with binary files.

Comment: Usually it’s more useful to have it in text mode, and only deal with `\n` line endings. It’s only when you really do want to go character-by-character like this that you want binary mode.

Comment: @DanielH. Yes, in that case, don't count on `ftell` to allocate the exact amount of memory for your file, for instance.

Comment: `char * stringOfFile = realloc(stringOfFile,i+1);` looks like a problem.  "'stringOfFile' is used uninitialized in this function".

Comment: Be aware that `fseek()` to the end of a binary file is implementation-dependent.  It works under POSIX and Windows, but it's explicitly undefined behavior.  Per [**7.21.9.2 The `fseek` function**, paragraph 3 of the C Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.2p3):  "A binary stream need not meaningfully support `fseek` calls with a `whence` value of `SEEK_END`."

Comment: @AndrewHenle I read that somewhere but couldn't find the reference. That's why I added the "read + realloc" method. For instance because `FILE` objects are used for `popen` as well. In that case you cannot `fseek`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    char tmp = getc(fp); //current letter in file
    int i=0;
    while (tmp != EOF) //End-Of-File (defined in stdio.h)
```

You need to check the value returned by `getc` for `EOF`. Instead, you convert it to a `char` and then check whether that's equal to `EOF` converted to a `char`. But what if the value of `char` that converts to `EOF` is actually in the file? Check the docs, `getc` returns an `int`.

You have other mistakes as well.

Comment: you're right. In a text file, it should work. In a general binary, it may detect the end too soon.

Comment: It might work and it might not. It's entirely possible that `EOF` is a value that, when converted to `char` and then back to `int` no longer compares equal to `EOF`. For example, if `EOF` was 1,000, converting that to `char` would certainly produce a number much less than 1,000, possibly even negative. Converting that back to `int` definitely won't give you 1,000. So it *might* work and it might not. I can't see how you can say it "should" work. What if `char` is signed and `EOF` is -1?